# ko.computed field for data-value

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

I develop web application, using html, javascript (include knockout, jquery).

I'm still a little new at knockout.

I need ko-computed field, that relative to data-value property of checkboxes.
But I have no idea how to do it.

Code sample:

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="action" data-value="A"/>
        <label>save</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="action" data-value="B" />
        <label>export</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="action" data-value="C" />
        <label>print</label>
```

I need property that will hand comma-string of data-value only of checked checkbox.

For example, if the first combo and the third combo are checked - I need the ko-computed field to have value: 'A,C'.

Is it possible? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a `computed`, a simple `observableArray` will do as well:

**HTML:**

```
<input value="A" type="checkbox" name="action" data-bind="checked: CheckedActions"/>
<label>save</label>

<input value="B" type="checkbox" name="action" data-bind="checked: CheckedActions"/>
<label>export</label>

<input value="C" type="checkbox" name="action" data-bind="checked: CheckedActions"/>
<label>print</label>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function VM() {
    this.CheckedActions = ko.observableArray();
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8VNY/7/)